# Magento2 Apply catalogrule on final price instead original price

Tags: magento2, price, special-price, catalog-rules

I have create catalog rule for all products by **50%**
if product has o**riginal price 100**
**special(final) price 80**
then after apply catalog rule it reduce by **50**(100%50).
I want it **40**(80%50).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can set the catalog rule for final price

->when you create the catalog price rule

->first you got to the action tab and in the **action tab**

```
Apply field Available
   ->there are i think 3 to 4 for option are available
   ->now select the **Adjust final price to this percentage**
```

than thats rule is apllied on the product final price